# How to sort questions by views?

Tags: support, feature-request, questions

Is it possible to sort questions by "most viewed" or "least viewed"? If not can we get that?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this directly from the site.  In the search bar you can search for `views:500` and get all questions with at least that many views.

If you really want all the questions, sorted by views, try this query in the data  explorer:

http://data.stackexchange.com/earthscience/query/53412

See also: [Can we have a sort by view count?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113042/can-we-have-a-sort-by-view-count)

Comment: +1 for letting us know we are already on the data explorer :) (I checked last week i think and we weren't: did it happen when we transitioned to public beta?)

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of already implemented. If you have access to the [2k moderation tools](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), you get access to a list of most viewed questions. This is what it looks like now:

> [image: list of most viewed questions]

It doesn't have a list of least viewed questions, and it only shows 3 most viewed questions. If you'd like more info, check casey's Data Explorer link, which will list them by the number of views.